# Vimeo oauth authorization page lacking "allow" button

Tags: python, api, oauth, vimeo

I'm using the Vimeo oauth api to allow access for my app. I retrieve an oauth_token and oauth_token_secret from the call to https://vimeo.com/oauth/request_token. But when I redirect the user to https://vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=REDACTED&permission=read, I get to a screen with the title "(My App Name) wants to access your Vimeo account" but no button on the screen to allow it.

I've also tried passing the callback_url (which matches the url I gave Vimeo when I signed up for the API), but that doesn't make a difference.

Has anyone see this before?

Comment: Same here, did you find any solution yet? (I am using scribe-java)

Comment: Nothing yet; other folks have commented on the same issue in the Video API forum.

Answer (score 0):

It's working again as of October 30.